# sub-family of cover with compact closure is still a cover?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Here is a problem about existence of exhaustion of a manifold:

> Denote manifold as $M$, with Hausdorff, second-countability and locally Euclidean property.
>   Show there exists a exhaustion of $M$.

And first part of proof is here:

> Since $M$ is second countable, there is a countable basis of the topology of $M$. Out of this countable sequence of open sets, we pick those that have compact closure, and denote them by $Y_1,Y_2,....$ Since $M$ is locally Euclidean it is easy to see that $\mathcal{Y}={Y_i}$ is a open cover of $M$.

And I’m confuse about the last part. How can locally Euclidean property grant $\mathcal{Y}$ be a sub-cover? I try to PBR but fail. Can anyone get me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we have to show is that every point of $M$ is contained in some $Y_i\in \mathcal Y$. So let $x\in M$ be arbitrary. Because $M$ is locally Euclidean, there is some open subset $U\subseteq M$ containing $x$ and a homeomorphism $\phi\colon U\to \widehat U$, where $\widehat U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\widehat x = \phi(x)$, and choose $r$ small enough that $B_{2r}(\widehat x)\subseteq \widehat U$. Then $\overline B_r(\widehat x)$ is compact and contained in $\widehat U$. Define
\begin{align*}
K & = \phi^{-1}\big(\overline B_r(\widehat x)\big),\\
W & = \phi^{-1}\big(B_r(\widehat x)\big).
\end{align*}
Since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, $W$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ contained in the compact set $K$.

Now there is a set $Y$ in our original basis such that $x\in Y \subseteq W$. Because $\overline Y$ is a closed subset of the compact set $K$, it is compact. Thus $Y$ is one of the sets in $\mathcal Y$.

Comment: Thanks! And is Hausdorff property applied in the proof of existence of P.O.U. ? It seems not clear in GTM218.

Comment: @NiacrosisHermit: The Hausdorff property is definitely needed. Without it, there's no basis of precompact open sets, for example. The line with two origins has no partition of unity subordinate to any open cover in which the two origins lie in different open sets.